# Stripe cancel a subscription in JS

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

The stripe docs do not contain a way to cancel subscriptions in JS. The Java way is to call:

```
Subscription subscription = Subscription.retrieve("sub_49ty4767H20z6a");
subscription.cancel();
```

I tried:

```
const subscription = stripe.subscriptions.cancel("sub_49ty4767H20z6a");
```

But this doesn't work. How do I cancel a subscription in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a subscription to cancel it is a non-sequitur. Here is the solution you're looking for:

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.update(
  user.stripe_subscription,
  {cancel_at_period_end: true}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To cancel a subscription you use `del`

`stripe.subscriptions.del("sub_49ty4767H20z6a")`

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel

Comment: `stripe.subscriptions.del` still works, but they updated the docs to `stripe.subscriptions.cancel`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

I'm using **`Node js`**

```
router. Post("/cancel-sub-test", async function (req, res, next) {
 const { planId, email, phone } = req.body;
 const customersData = await stripeTest.customers.list();
 let findData = customersData.data.find((x) => x.email === email);
 let customer = findData; // find customer/user

 const customerGet = await stripeTest.customers.retrieve(customer.id, {
  expand: ["subscriptions"],
 });

const [subscriptions] = customerGet.subscriptions.data; //subscription id

const resp = await stripeTest.subscriptions.cancel(subscriptions.id); //cancel subscription 

 res.send({
  status: resp.status,
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue with nodejs as backend file,then working with firestore functions, adding the link of the function to the kotlin in android studio as frontend, this video can help you how to integrate stripe to android app https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4T025cEmjg&t=808s:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_....');

exports.cancelSubscription = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    try {
      const userUID = request.body.userUID;
  
      const customersData = await stripe.customers.list();
      console.log('Customers data:', customersData); 
  
      let findData = customersData.data.find((x) => x.userUID === userUID);
  
      if (!findData) {
        console.error('Customer data not found for userUID:', userUID); 
        throw new Error('Customer data not found');
      }
  
      const customerGet = await stripe.customers.retrieve(findData.id, {
        expand: ["subscriptions"],
      });
      console.log('Customer data:', customerGet); 
     
      if (!customerGet.subscriptions || customerGet.subscriptions.data.length === 0) {
        console.error('No subscriptions found for customer:', findData.id); 
        throw new Error('No subscriptions found for the customer');
      }
     
      const [subscription] = customerGet.subscriptions.data; 
     
      const resp = await stripe.subscriptions.cancel(subscription.id); 
      console.log('Cancellation response:', resp); 
     
      response.send({
        status: resp.status,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error cancelling subscription:', error);
      response.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  });
```